# Attach Title column edit properties to another column

Tags: sharepoint-online

As we know, when we create SharePoint List it have a "Title" default column, but is not a simple column, it have "Title (linked to item with edit menu)", So we can clic on `...` and click edit

[image]

I want to know if it´s possible to attach that edit menu to another column. Regards

Comment: If you just want `Edit Item` link and not the full `ECB Menu`, you can use CSR to provide a custom link that points to the edit item.

Comment: But how can I use it into another column, because I´m planning to hide "Title" column @RohitWaghela

Comment: Always has been insane that SharePoint couldn't allow this easily...

Comment: @Ledwing Please check the answer I have posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow below steps :

1. Open your `AllItems` View In SharePoint designer in advanced mode.
2. search for the `<ViewFields>` tag in your `XmlDefinition`.
3. And within this tag, add the `ListItemMenu="TRUE"` to the field in front of which you want to show the ECB Menu/Context menu. (Refer below screenshot. Here I am adding `ECB Menu/Context menu` in front of field name `test`)

[image]

**4. OutPut**

[image]

**5. Now you can remove your Title field**

Comment: I think such approach doesnt work in Sharepoint online modern experience, does it ?

Comment: @Alberto I have not tested it on Modern experience. Once I will do, I will share the details and update the answer accordingly :)

Comment: @RohitWaghela, can you please help me with this https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/280467/attach-title-column-edit-properties-to-another-column-in-sharepoint-online

Answer (score 1):

I've often found that if there is another column where I'd like to have the ECB menu appear, it's normally because it's the primary column for that particular list.

If that's the case, changing the 'Column Name' (Display name) of your 'Title' field works well. You do this via the following steps:

1. Go to your List Settings
2. Click 'Title' under Columns
3. Change 'Column name' to your desired name

In this scenario, you don't create your other column, as you're just repurposing your 'Title' field to reflect the column you associate as the primary identifier of your list items.

This is a good way to re-purpose the built-in functionality you get with the 'Title' field, while still allowing you to display the column with your unique name. Also, you won't have to make any changes to views, etc... in order to take advantage of the built-in functionality that the 'Title' field offers.

This may not meet your needs each time, but I thought I'd share this answer, since it often will do the trick.

[image]

Cheers,
Matt

Comment: If you have a simple text column it can be solution, in my case my list haven´t a text column, just choice, calculated and Groyp columns. But it works for another users who want to change name of Title column

Comment: In those cases I sometimes set up a workflow that runs on add and update that copies the other column value into the Title field. I also then hide the Title field on the NewForm and EditForm pages. Kinda works ok. Sometimes there is a delay in the workflow running and the list view that NewForm or EditForm redirects to does not have the value in the Title field yet.