# How to remove default "Title" from a list, but keep the "..." edit option?

Tags: list, 2016, title-column

I have a list. I would like to remove/hide the default "Title" column. But I would like to keep the options for the users to edit/delete the elements by clicking on the "...". Is that archiveable somehow?

The list was generated by an outer company, but they simply added an other field as title and ignored the default one. They migrated data so there are more than 1400 record where the original "Title" is "-", but the users are forced to add some text when try to create a new item. Also if I turn of the display by CSS and remove it from the list by changing the view, the "..." option is also removed what would be important for the users. On top of that the outer company used infopath so I can't replace the title field they used with the original and rename + copy all value to the original, because it would mess up with the rules they added in the infopath... So the solution would be to remove the original Title field and keep the "..." somehow.

Thanks for any advice how to deal with this mess!

Comment: Why don't you include Edit field in the view?

Comment: Edit field force the users to open a new window to edit. It is much faster if they can delete items directly from the list view. Also at the training the users learnt to use the "..." to edit, so we should repeat the training or communicate the change for the whole company and we want to avoid that.

Comment: Refer this link. This has already been answered here. - https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/225003/attach-title-column-edit-properties-to-another-column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

... appears because of LinkToItem property on list.
To enable link to item and/or edit menu options on any of the SharePoint list column, follow below steps:

1. Open your List view page in SharePoint Designer using "Edit File in Advanced Mode"
2. Search for  Tag. Pick the appropriate field to have link to item functionality
   Add: LinkToItem="TRUE" to it.

   ```
   <FieldRef Name="ProjectName" LinkToItem="TRUE" ListItemMenu="TRUE" />
   ```
3. Save and close the page. Now, if you go back to your view, the "Project Name" field will have the link to DispForm.aspx page of the item!

Comment: I found in SharePoint Designer 2013, one of these attributes will be stripped out on Save.