# SharePoint 2013 Issue Tracker App- Columns "Title" and "Related Issues"

Tags: sharepoint-server, issue-tracking

I need to update the "Title" column to be a drop down option.  Where do I go to change that option.  It currently only allows for a "single line item".

Comment: No, you can't change the system generated [Title] column from Test to any other types. You can update the name though. Also, you can hide it from the data entry Form. You need to create a new column to meet your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

As Matiur said, it is not possible to change the column type of "Title".

Go to list Settings>Advanced settings>Set "Allow management of content types? " to YES.

Click on your content type -> Click Title Column, set the column as hidden, then create a new drop down column.

[image]

Comment: Thank you both very much!  This was extremely helpful!

Comment: It removed the "edit item" option; says that it was attached the "Title"; is there a way to add it to the new column I created?

Comment: Check as follows: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/225003/attach-title-column-edit-properties-to-another-column/225006#225006