# Lists - Where is the "Edit Item" dropdown

Tags: sharepoint-server, list

I made some updates to columns and it removed the "edit item" option; says that it was attached the "Title"; is there a way to add it to the new column I created?

Comment: Yes. You can attach it to any another columns through SharePoint Designer. Refer below link I ha ve already answerd the steps to achieve this - https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/225003/attach-title-column-edit-properties-to-another-column/225006#225006

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the edit menu on default column “**Title (linked to item with edit menu)**”, it is not possible to add this to a custom column.

That is the default **Title** column provided in a list and you will need the column to enter the edit menu.

[image]

Comment: FYI we can attach this callout menu to other columns as well. please refer this - https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/225003/attach-title-column-edit-properties-to-another-column/225006#225006

Comment: @RohitWaghela Great! Thanks for sharing. You can post this comment as a separate answer so that it can be accepted then.